# Should I set the world matrix before rendering polygons in XNA?

Tags: matrix, 3d, xna

In XNA, I can change the world matrix when rendering polygons with vertexes (either buffered or dynamic) to shift their position in the world, without having to reconstruct the vertex arrays.  In OpenGL, popping and pushing matrixes (i.e. changing the world matrix) is how you render things at various positions, however, I'm not sure whether this is considered to be the correct way of doing this in XNA.

Is adjusting the world matrix on a per model / per object basis to render them the correct way of doing it in XNA, or should I reconstruct the vertex arrays when I want to draw something at a different position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to recosntruct...

The right way is passing the object's world transformation to the effect, and the associated vertex shader will use it to transform your vertex in the GPU.